# Dropdown at the end of Model dialog

Tags: jquery, html

Edit:

Opening up a dropdown (placed right at bottom of dialog) in JDialog (with modal behavior), doesn't display the entire dropdown.

I have tried z-index, but still not working.

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `style="height: 50px;"`

Alsom can you please post some code? maybe we can help better!

try [THIS](http://ugate.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/scrollable-twitter-bootstrap-menus/) and [THIS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1989) and [THIS](http://www.htmlforums.com/html-xhtml/t-how-do-i-make-drop-down-list-wider-than-field-35905.html)